# Подсветка строк в html-файле

Tags: phpstorm

Что означает и как убрать такую подсветку строк

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по скриншоту, не устраивает бледно-зеленый фон? Похоже, у вас там какой-то language injection, которого по умолчанию быть не должно. Приложите, пожалуйста, скриншот странички `Settings | Editor | Language Injections`

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял какая именно подсветка имеется в виду, но вам нужно смотреть в сторону настроек

1. Общие: Settings → Editor → Colors&Fonts

   Если речь шла о подсветке строки, то она находятся далее по списку:

   → General → Caret row

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Также можно настраивать подсветку непосредственно для ЯП или гиперразметки

   - Settings → Editor → Colors&Fonts → HTML
   - Settings → Editor → CodeStyle → HTML

Comment: Большое спасибо!
Но такого сочетания настроек не нашел (PhpStorm 2017).
Caret row - вообще не нашел ((??

Comment: @Oleg может у вас на русском?) Попробуйте по поиску в строке (верхний левый угол) ввести

Comment: Алексей, спасибо!
Не находится ((??

Случилась еще одна беда - шарясь по настройкам теперь например соочетание Ctrl+Alt+S не открывает settings - вместо этого сочетания теперь в File предлагается сочетание Meta+Comma ??
Что я натворил как вернуться ???

Answer (score 0):

В `Intelij Idea` это делается как-то так:

[image: как-то так]

В `PhpStorm`, я думаю, аналогичное что-то должно быть.

Comment: Судя по скриншоту, не устраивает бледно-зеленый фон? Похоже, у вас там какой-то language injection, ко торого по умолчанию быть не должно. Приложите, пожалуйста, скриншот странички `Settings | Editor | Language Injections`

Comment: ой, это должен был быть комментарий к вопросу выше:)

Comment: Лена, спасибо!
Не устраивают темно-зеленые строки (сплошные).
Скрин ша сделаю.

Comment: У меня PhpStorm 2017 - такой раскладки нет и эти темно-зеленые полосы-строки только в html файлах (где-то сбил настройку, а где не могу найти)